# Macro not found when trying to run an Excel sub with VBS

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I've found the following code online to try an automate an Excel macro.

```
 ' Create a WshShell to get the current directory
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Create an Excel instance
Dim myExcelWorker
Set myExcelWorker = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 


Dim strSaveDefaultPath
Dim strPath
strSaveDefaultPath = myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath
strPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strPath

' Open the Workbook specified on the command-line 
Dim oWorkBook
Dim strWorkerWB
strWorkerWB = strPath & "\Excel Report Creator.xlsm"

Set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Open(strWorkerWB,0, true)

' Build the macro name with the full path to the workbook
Dim strMacroName
strMacroName = "'" & strPath & "\Excel Report Creator" & "!ReferenceSheet.CommandButton1_Click"

on error resume next 
    myExcelWorker.Run strMacroName
   if err.number <> 0 Then
   MsgBox "errerr: " & err.Description
   End If
   err.clear
on error goto 0 

oWorkBook.Save 

myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strSaveDefaultPath

    ' Clean up and shut down
        Set oWorkBook = Nothing
        myExcelWorker.Quit
        Set myExcelWorker = Nothing
        Set WshShell = Nothing
```

When ran I receive the following error.

```
The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

My spread sheet is called Excel Report Creator.xlsm, the sheet is called ReferenceSheet, and the sub is CommandButton1_Click. Am I missing anything here? Possibly a setting within Excel?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: I would guess that your document is not trusted or in a trusted location, so when you open it in VBS, Excel won't allow the macros to run without a user clicking on the yellow `Enable macros` message bar. Go into the `Trust Center` in Excel and set `<path-to-"Excel Report Creator.xlsm"` to be a trusted location & you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I added my excel file, but I'm still receiving the error.

Comment: When you directly open the file in Excel do you get the macro disabled warning? You may want to try adding the entire folder as a trusted location. If that doesn't help, I'm out of my league.

Comment: I don't get any warnings. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the workbook name has spaces you need to wrap it in single quotes.  And you don't need the full path if the workbook is open:

```
' Build the macro name with the full path to the workbook
Dim strMacroName
strMacroName = "'Excel Report Creator.xlsm'" & _
               "!ReferenceSheet.CommandButton1_Click"

on error resume next 
    myExcelWorker.Run strMacroName
   if err.number <> 0 Then
   MsgBox "errerr: " & err.Description
   End If
   err.clear
on error goto 0
```

And make sure the Sub you're calling is `Public`

Comment: Worked great. Now I'm getting an error saying "Microsoft Excel: We can't save 'Excel Report Creator.xlsm' because the file is read-only." Guess I'll start another question. Thanks.

Comment: You opened the file as read-only by passing `true` to the third parameter of the `open()` method.  Don't do that if you want to save the file.